# getting Bad Request during opening a querystring file in CURL

Tags: php, curl, fopen, file-get-contents

```
$URL:https://demo.firstach.com/https/TransRequest.asp?Login_ID=someit&Transaction_Key=somekey&Customer_ID=23&Customer_Name=Muhammad Naeem&Customer_Address=Address&Customer_City=city&Customer_State=HI&Customer_Zip=54000&Customer_Phone=--&Customer_Bank_ID=111111118&Customer_Bank_Account=12345678901234567890&Account_Type=Business Checking&Transaction_Type=Debit&Frequency=Once&Number_of_Payments=1&Effective_Date=12%2F05%2F2010&Amount_per_Transaction=10.00&Check_No=&Memo=&SECCType=WEB 

$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); // set url to post to 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // return into a variable 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0); // times out after Ns 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // run the whole process 

    print_r($result); 

    curl_close($ch);
```

i also used file_get_conent and fopen but all are returning me BAD REQUEST error,
please help me out

for more detail please see the link below

http://www.uqwibble.com/Phase-2/ach.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assumign the code you posted is accurate then this line is the issue:

```
$URL:https://demo.firstach.com/https/TransRequest.asp?Login_ID=someit&Transaction_Key=somekey&Customer_ID=23&Customer_Name=Muhammad Naeem&Customer_Address=Address&Customer_City=city&Customer_State=HI&Customer_Zip=54000&Customer_Phone=--&Customer_Bank_ID=111111118&Customer_Bank_Account=12345678901234567890&Account_Type=Business Checking&Transaction_Type=Debit&Frequency=Once&Number_of_Payments=1&Effective_Date=12%2F05%2F2010&Amount_per_Transaction=10.00&Check_No=&Memo=&SECCType=WEB
```

here it looks liek you attemtp to define `$URL` but when you use it with cURL you are referencing `$url`. The varibales are case sensitive. Secondly you have `$URL:` which is not valid you want to use `$url =`.

Addiitonally i would encode the params like this:

```
$baseurl = 'https://demo.firstach.com/https/TransRequest.asp';
$params = array(
 'Login_ID' =>  'someit',
 'Transaction_Key' => 'somekey',
 'Customer_ID'= => 23,
 'Customer_Name' => 'Muhammad Naeem',
 'Customer_Address' => 'Address',
 'Customer_City' => 'city',
 'Customer_State' => 'HI',
 'Customer_Zip' => '54000',
 'Customer_Phone' => '--',
 'Customer_Bank_ID' => '111111118'
 'Customer_Bank_Account' => '12345678901234567890'
 'Account_Type' => 'Business Checking'
 'Transaction_Type' => 'Debit'
 'Frequency' => 'Once'
 'Number_of_Payments' => 1,
 'Effective_Date'=> '12/05/2010',
 'Amount_per_Transaction' => '10.00',
 'Check_No'=> '',
 'Memo'=> '',
 'SECCType' => 'WEB'
);

$url = sprintf('%s?%s', $baseurl, http_build_query($params));
```

That way `http_build_query` will take care of all your url encoding and you can work with an array before hand so its easy to see whats going on and add/remove/change paramters. Alternatively if its a post request you could jsut use:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);`

which will take care of all the parameter encoding and what not directly from the array this way they dont need to be appended manually to the `$url`.